# Why Text.Regex.Posix =~ matches characters with \d?

Tags: regex, haskell, posix

Can someone explain how this interaction in ghci is possible?

```
*Main Text.Regex.Posix> "d1" =~ "\\d" :: String
"d"
*Main Text.Regex.Posix> "d1" =~ "\\d" :: Int
1
```

I thought that `\d` standed for digit, so I don't understand how it can match the character `d` and not the character `1` present on the string.

Note: Using ghci 7.10.3

Comment: `\d` doesn't mean anything special in POSIX regexes. It just matches `d`. Try `[[:digit:]]` instead.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`Text.Regex.Posix` module](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-posix-0.95.2/docs/Text-Regex-Posix.html) only supports *c posix regex api*. POSIX regex syntax does not define `\d` as a shorthand character class for digits, instead, it has `[:digit:]` POSIX character class that must be used inside *bracket expressions*, e.g. `[[:digit:]]`. However, it is as easier and shorter to use `[0-9]` to match regular ASCII digits.

To use `\d` in your patterns, you may want to use [*Text.Regex.PCRE*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/regex-pcre-0.94.4/docs/Text-Regex-PCRE-Wrap.html).

Comment: Oh these brackets! Thank you.